# Android OpenGL ES 1.1 white box textures

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures

I am having an issue where textures from the resources become just white.
The issue only seems to occur on phones (Droid-X for sure), but it works just fine on the emulator.
I have researched this issue for days and tried so many things. 

Textures are POT ranging from 8x8 to 128x128 
Textures have been in res/drawable, res/drawable-nodpi and res/raw 
Tried with and without this in the manifest file:

```
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" />
```

I am at a complete loss on this.

Here is the code I am using 
gl is GL10 and gl11 is GL11

```
During onSurfaceCreated
gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);
gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_LIGHTING);

gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_FLAT);
gl.glClearColor(0.00f, 0.00f, 0.00f, 1.00f);
gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_DST_ALPHA);
gl.glOrthof(-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1);
gl.glColor4f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);

gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);

gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

gl.glTexEnvf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL10.GL_REPLACE);
gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);

gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
```

During onSurfaceChanged

```
gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
gl.glLoadIdentity();
gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
gl.glLoadIdentity();
gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
```

Generating the VBO:

```
public final float vertices[] = { 
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f
};
public float textureCoord[] = { 
    0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f
};
public final byte indices[] = { 
    0, 1, 3,
    0, 3, 2 
};
verticesBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 
    Constants.FLOAT_SIZE).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
textureCoordBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(textureCoord.length * 
    Constants.FLOAT_SIZE).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
indicesBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

// fill buffers
verticesBuffer.put(vertices);
textureCoordBuffer.put(textureCoord);
indicesBuffer.put(indices);

// set pointer positions
verticesBuffer.position(0);
textureCoordBuffer.position(0);
indicesBuffer.position(0);

// temp buffer array
int[] buffer = new int[1];

// VERTICES BUFFER.
gl11.glGenBuffers(1, buffer, 0);
verticesBufferIndex = buffer[0];
gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesBufferIndex);
final int vertexSize = verticesBuffer.capacity() * Constants.FLOAT_SIZE;
gl11.glBufferData(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexSize, verticesBuffer, GL11.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// TEXTURE COORD BUUFER
gl11.glGenBuffers(1, buffer, 0);
textureCoordBufferIndex = buffer[0];
gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textureCoordBufferIndex);
final int texCoordSize = textureCoordBuffer.capacity() * Constants.FLOAT_SIZE;
gl11.glBufferData(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texCoordSize, textureCoordBuffer, GL11.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// clear buffer id
gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

// Unbind the array buffer.
gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
gl11.glGenBuffers(1, buffer, 0);

// INDICES BUFFER
indicesBufferIndex = buffer[0];
gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicesBufferIndex);
final int indexSize = indicesBuffer.capacity();
gl11.glBufferData(GL11.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexSize, indicesBuffer, GL11.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// Unbind the element array buffer.
gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesBufferIndex);
gl11.glVertexPointer(3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textureCoordBufferIndex);
gl11.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicesBufferIndex);

BitmapFactory.Options sBitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
sBitmapOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444;

// many of these calls :
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(resources.openRawResource(resourceID), null, sBitmapOptions);
int[] textures = new int[1];
gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
mCropWorkspace[0] = 0;
mCropWorkspace[1] = bitmap.getHeight();
mCropWorkspace[2] = bitmap.getWidth();
mCropWorkspace[3] = -bitmap.getHeight();
((GL11) gl).glTexParameteriv(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
GL11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_CROP_RECT_OES, mCropWorkspace, 0);
GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
bitmap.recycle();
return texture[0]; // which gets stored into textureID for later
```

During onDrawFrame

```
gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

// and many of these
gl11.glPushMatrix();
// transfomations
gl11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
gl11.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, indicesCount, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
gl11.glPopMatrix();
```

Sorry for all the code but I think everything is there.
Thank you,
Will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must enable vertex array and texture coords array and bind your buffer indexes before making any calls to your `glDraw...()` function.

After `glBindTexture()` in `onDrawFrame()`, put this:

```
gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

GL11 gl11 = (GL11) gl;

gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesBufferIndex);
gl11.glVertexPointer(3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textureCoordBufferIndex);
gl11.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0); 
gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicesBufferIndex);

// Draw...
```

Comment: I have that inside of the onSurfaceCreated because it never changes, I placed it at the beginning of the onDrawFrame and then for each item I bind the correct texture index as shown above. Since the texture coord, vertices and indices never change it should only need to be binded once right? The prorgam works absolutly fine on the emulator(1.6 and 2.2) with no opengl error produced.

Comment: @Will McG: Well, there are cases where you'll get a new different `GL` context in `onDrawFrame()` and therefore you must rebind it.

Comment: Lannér: No luck there, I told it to generate the hardware buffers on every frame, not just bind the old ones. My brother is trying it out on his Evo4G and he is getting a completely black screen where as I am getting the white boxes. Not sure if that is the same issue but it is new information.

Comment: Somehow I have solved the issue. I mainly deleted most of it and based it more accurately on the SpriteMethodText and ReplicaIslasnd. I THINK my issue may have been during the loading of the bitmaps using GLUtils.texImage2D. On some other site someone mention that gl.glTexParameterf does not always maintain its state and must be called before every call to GLUtils.texImage2D. Like I said I THINK this may have been the issue since I do not think I have changed anything else.

Comment: I was having the same issue, having checked texture sizes and cut back my code to bare bones... it was like you said, I have to call glTexParameterf right before calling GLUtils.texImage2D. Fixed it right away by changing that. Thank you.

Comment: @WillMcG Yes, doing what you've suggested solved it for me as well.